# VBA-Simultaneously paste and concat cell values and formats from 1 sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

Please see attached, [question](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Ar0y71vBm1oLfjFIvRjN01s-hs8). I have sheet 1 and sheet 2. There are two cells in sheet 2 with conditional statements and conditional formatting as well.

I would like to paste the values and formatting of these two cells in two different lines in ONE cell in sheet 1 using VBA macro.

If I use:

```
Cells(BtRng.Row, 3) = .Range("F11").Value & vbNewLine & .Range("F12").Value
```

It does the job without appreciating the formats.

I would prefer to only have the values and formats rather than the entire conditional statement pasted but if that's the only way, then I'll live with it!

I tried various .Copy and .PasteSpecial scenarios but couldn't figure it out. I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: hi. i believe that u cant have to distict formats in one cell.. u must copy the values, and then choose one format and pastSpecial

Comment: Take a look at the answers here.  They're fairly specific to your issue.  If you have any issues implementing, check back, update what code you currently have and have attempted to write and we'll go from there. https://superuser.com/questions/527746/coloring-partial-text-within-cell-in-excel